# changePassword() method in Firebase version 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase ver 3.2.1 in my React Native iOS project. I read the log from version 2.4.2 [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/changepassword.html), there is a method named **changePassword()** which can be used to change user's password.

But when I look docs for Firebase ver 3.2.1 I can't find any method named **changePassword()**. So I'm wondering, is **changePassword()** method can not be used in Firebase version 3 anymore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since **Firebase v3.0**, `changePassword` method is not available anymore. If you need to reset your user's password you can use custom email action handlers : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

> The following user management actions require the user to complete the action using an email action handler: **Resetting passwords**

I recommend you read the documentation and you'll get started really quick to reset your user's password.

**EDIT :** If you don't need to reset the password but just update it, you can use the `updatePassword` method.

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
let newPassword = getASecureRandomPassword();

user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(() => {
  // Update successful.
}, (error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
```

> **Important:** To set a user's password, the user must have signed in recently. See Re-authenticate a user.

More informations here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 17):

```
firebase.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword('email', 'oldPassword')
        .then(function(user) {

            firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePassword('newPassword').then(function(){

                //Do something

            }).catch(function(err){
                //Do something
            });

        }).catch(function(err){
            //Do something
        });
```

Comment: This works like a charm! just copy and paste and see the magic :D

Comment: this is great thanks i changed the function to es6 arrow function but other then that awesome!